# Does creating a RESTful API with rails follow an MVC Architecture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

An application I was just assigned to uses an ASP.NET MVC framework for the UI layer. It then got me thinking about Ruby on Rails and it's MVC architecture as well.

When I helped build a RESTful API with rails I didn't really use a View... Just the Controller for the RESTful endpoint and the Model.

Does that mean that the RESTful endpoint built on Rails does not follow an MVC architecture even though Rails supposedly does?

Or does the fact that Rails follows an MVC architecture mean that the RESTful endpoint built on rails also follows an MVC framework even though there isn't really a view?

I wonder this because my current application uses the ASP.NET MVC Framework for it's UI, yet only has a View and a Controller, and makes AJAX calls to web services to get Data to display. I thought to myself that it didn't follow an MVC structure, which led me to this after thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Rails API was still MVC. The "view" component was probably just generated implicitly, so to speak. That is, Rails sometimes uses a set of default behaviors for generating implicit views. In an API, for example, if you use `respond_to :json` and `respond_with(@my_object)` then a JSON "view" will be auto-generated as the response from `@my_object.to_json`. You can override this "view" by overriding the `@my_object.as_json` method... or you can get fancy and add a Presenter layer to your object and have it generate the JSON "view" code. Either way, it's still MVC even if you don't have an explicit view template all the time.

Also, some Rails gems exist, such as [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl), which make the "view" component/approach more explicit if you like that style.

Comment: Okay so the Rails API was still MVC. What about the ASP.NET UI? It uses the ASP.NET MVC framework, yet only uses the View and Controller. It doesn't have a Model component, yet still gets data using AJAX calls to services that use ORM to manipulate data.
Can I consider that MVC (although it doesn't have an explicit Model component)? Or is it only applications without an explicit View that can still be considered MVC?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't feel comfortable answering for ASP.NET. But I don't think my answer should be taken to mean that only the "view" component can be implicitly handled. MVC is a way of organizing responsibilities. If your ASP.NET framework has a dedicated component for business logic that is separate from the controller then it may be considered a "model" still. But it sort of sounds like more of a View-Controller setup.